# What are permissions to create a folder or file?

Tags: permissions

I've seen lots of stuff on the internet about HOW to set permissions.

Please tell me WHAT permissions are required for a user to be able to create a folder or a file.
I would have thought just w but I'm not sure.

Comment: The only permissions are read, write, and execute.  What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?  It's better to ask about the actual problem and provide details and context than ask a coded/vague question that won't actually help you solve the problem.

Comment: small addition: the directory -above- where you want to make a dir or file needs to be rwx for your user and/or your group and/or others depending on the user used to create it.

Answer (score 1):

To change file and directory permissions change directories with `cd` to the directory that contains the file/directory whose permissions you want to change, and use the command `chmod` (change mode).

Add write permissions to a file or a directory:

```
chmod +w filename
chmod +w directoryname
```

If you want to read the file and also want write permissions, you need read permissions too. Add read/write permissions to a file or a directory:

```
chmod +rw filename
chmod +rw directoryname
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux (and all Unix-like operating systems), there's the principle that "everything is a file". That includes, among other things, directories. A directory is basically a file that contains information about the contents of the directory.

So if you have, for example, the directory `/home/kristy/some_files/` and want to create a new file (or a new subfolder) in this directory, you need to *write* to the file representing this directory. And in order to do that, you need write permissions on this directory.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Apparently I was right: the user needs w.
The permissions on my folder are:
drw-rw-rw-   2 www-data www-data  4096 Dec 20 20:05 tmp
Yet when I try to write a file to it from a php called shell_exec command I get this:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/tmp/TestTopics.txt'

How can I make the www-data user able to write a file to /var/www/tmp ?

Comment: Sorry, this forum is very restrictive.

The permissions on the folder: /var/www/tmp are
drw-rw-rw-   2 www-data www-data  4096 Dec 20 20:05 tmp

I'm trying to create/write a file to the tmp folder in Python from a php shell_exec command.
I'm getting this error in Python:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/tmp/TestTopics.txt'

How can I make the www-data user able to create a file in /var/www/tmp ?

Comment: @kristy1024 This isn't a forum, I'm afraid. You may want to look at the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to find out how this site is intended to be used. Regarding your (new) question, write permission on the directory should allow any user that has this permission to create a new file in the directory. If the file already exists, you need to look at the file's permissions. Also check that your programs or scripts actually are running as `www-data` , that's not necessarily the case. The details may depend on how exactly you have set up your system.